# Running multiple django projects using docker and nginx

Tags: django, docker, nginx, devops

I am trying to do the following.

- I have 3 django projects (NOT apps) (can be more).
- Proj1: On port **8000**, Proj2: **8001**, and Proj3:**8002**

**This is what I am trying to achieve:**

User visits : *localhost:8000*

All urls under Pr1: Respond

User visits: *localhost:8000/Pr2*

All urls under Pr2: Respond

User visits: *localhost:8000/Pr3*

All urls under Pr3: Respond

**Goal**: Proj 1 is run with Docker and Nginx. Now I have 2 new projects to integrate. Every new sub project should be reached using only one main port (8000). But internally the request is directed towards the correct port of sub-project.

**Why this goal**: Achieve micro-service style structure. Sub projects (2 & 3) can be reached only after authentication through Proj1.

**What have I tried**: Honestly no clear idea where to start.

- Added new projects to docker-compose...they all work when visited by their own port(localhost:8001/Prj2) ..
- With nginx, tried adding a new server. No effect:

  ```
    server {
        listen 8001;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://web_socket:8080;
            proxy_redirect     off;
        }
    }
  ```

Comment: If you want to mount 3 different apps under different path prefixes, you'd need separate `location /Pr2 { ... }` blocks in the Nginx configuration. However, that won't help you with authentication.

Answer (score 1):

If you have "nginx" installed, so you can just create two files (site1.com.conf, site2.com.conf) in the following directory: "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/"
Then add inside this files codes below:
**site1.com.conf**

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream site1 {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:49151; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name site1.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /var/www/site1.com/src/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/site1.com/src/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  site1;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

**site2.com.conf**

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream site2 {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:49152; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name site2.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /var/www/site2.com/src/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/site2.com/src/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  site2;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

Then edit "/etc/hosts" and add there two lines:
*127.0.0.1       site1.com

127.0.0.1       site2.com*

After saving files, restart uwsgi (install if it is not installed) and **nginx**

**service uwsgi restart**

**sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart**

**Note: all your django applications should be in the folder of "/var/www/site1.com/src" and "/var/www/site2.com/src"**